# Laravel Auth logout not working -- Earlier posted answers for this question are not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have developed small application for Auth learning purpose where everything works fine Login Logout and Dashboard page. But

**Case1** once after clicking on logout, try to access dashboard page by editing url in browser it goes to dashboard page which is wrong.

**Case2** when i clear cache and browsing data and try to access dashboard it works fine and redirect for login which is correct.

I am using Auth::logout for log out. Following is my code

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/login','AuthenticationController@login')->name('login');

Route::post('/login.submit','AuthenticationController@getLogIn')->
name('login.submit');

Route::get('/register','AuthenticationController@register')->name('register');

Route::post('/register.submit','AuthenticationController@addUser')->
name('register.submit');

Route::get('/logout','AuthenticationController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:user'],function(){

    Route::get('/dashboard','AuthenticationController@dashboard')->
    name('dashboard');

});
```

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


   
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User1::class,
        ],

       
    ]
```

AuthenticationController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Models\User1;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Session;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }


    public function login()
    {
        return view('login');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        return view('register');
    }
    public function addUser(Request $request)
    {
        $input=$request->all();

        
        $Validator=Validator::make($input,$this->getRegisterRules($input));
        if($Validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($Validator->messages());
        }

        $input['password']=bcrypt($input['password']);
        $user=User1::Create($input);
        if($user->exists)
        {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('success','User created successfully! Kindly login');
        }
    }
    private function getRegisterRules($input) {
        $return = array();
        $return['fname'] = 'required|min:4|max:20';
        $return['lname'] = 'required|min:4|max:20';
        $return['email'] = 'required|email';
        $return['password'] = 'required|min:4|max:20|confirmed';
        return $return;
    }
    private function messages() {
        return [
            // 'question.required'  => 'The question field is required.'
        ];
    }
    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
     public function getLogIn(Request $request)
    {
        $input=$request->all();

        $Validator=Validator::make($input,$this->getLoginRules($input));
        if($Validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($Validator->messages());
        }
        
        if(Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember))
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors('Invalid user name or password!');

    }
    public function getLoginRules($input)
    {
        $return=array();

        $return['email']='required|email';
        $return['password']='required|min:4|max:20';
        return $return;
    } 
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('success','You have logged out!');
    }  
}
```

App/Models/User1.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User1 extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=[
        'fname',
        'lname',
        'email',
        'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
  <div id="formContent">
    <!-- Tabs Titles -->
    @if(session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert-success">
      {{session('success')}}
    </div>
    @endif
  <!-- Login Form -->
    
    @if($errors->any())
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first()}}
      </div>
    @endif

    <form method="POST" action="{{url('login.submit')}}">
      
      <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="email" placeholder="Username">
      @if($errors->has('email'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first('email')}}
      </div>
      @endif
      
      @csrf
      <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" 
      name="password" placeholder="Password">
      @if($errors->has('password'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first('password')}}
      </div>
      @endif
      
      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
      
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember"  value="1" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember me
    </form>

    <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
    <div id="formFooter">
      <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a class="underlineHover" href="{{url('register')}}">SignUp</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
  <?php //dd(session()->all()); ?>
  <div id="formContent">
    Welcome To Dashboard
  </div>
  <form action="{{url('logout')}}" method="GET"> 
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Logout">
  </form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i try to `dd(session->all())` in dashboard.blade.php following is the output

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "Uz8bUpJry6majKAb3yW7FuYqgjppzqroJqjcMPq4"
  "url" => array:1 [▶]
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "login_user_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 7
]
```

**Following is the list of route**

[image]

Comment: laravel8 version

Answer (score 4):

I have made one change in line of code and my issue get solved.

**Auth::logout()** changed to **Auth::guard('user')->logout();**

Comment: Great! You did it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('user')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse([], 204)
            : redirect()->route('login')->with('success','You have logged out!');
    }
```

Comment: _Why_ should OP "try this"? What was wrong with the code? What did you change?

Comment: It throws guard does not exist

Comment: try this `Auth::guard('user')->logout();`

Comment: again error 'Method App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticationController::loggedOut does not exist.'

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 9.19 and Sanctum 3.0. I had the same issue and solved it like this —

```php
public function logout(Request $req)
    {
        try {
            $bearer_token = $req->bearerToken();
            $token = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($bearer_token);
            $token->delete();

            return response([
                'data' => 'logged out successfully'
            ], 200);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ], 400);
        }
    }
```